# Predicates#and: any way to access the internal predicates?

Tags: java, guava, predicates

I'm using

`andPredicate = Predicates.and(firstPredicate, secondPredicate);`

Now I have to serialize the `andPredicate` (as a JsonObject) and need to access the internal list of the used predicates to gain access to the members of each single predicate.

Is there a way to access these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need behavior like this, the answer is to whip up your own version of Predicates.and(), which isn't too hard at all.    Guava's internal implementation for Predicates.and is (correctly) an implementation detail, rather than something exposed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no direct way to get this.

Anyway, as a workaround, you could use the toString() method of the andPredicate object.
The implementation for this method (listed [here](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#line.329) ) will return a value like this:

```
And(<firstPredicate.toString()>, <secondPredicate.toString()>)
```

Where you can get the parenthesis content, and analyze each entry.

As every entry could also be an `and`, `or`, or another compose predicate, be careful on handling the commas and parenthesis.

Comment: Seems that way. `Predicates` uses the `private static class  Predicates.AndPredicate` which offers no access to the internal components.

Answer (score 1):

As the class [Javadoc](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html) states, andPredicate is already serializable:

> All methods returns serializable predicates as long as they're given
>   serializable parameters.

Comment: I wasn't clear on what I meant with serializing. I need to create a JsonObject out of the predicate, for that I need access to its members.